# Angular http, download photo function not working on Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, angular-httpclient

I wonder why the code below works on chrome and edge but not on firefox.

```
downloadFile(uri, name){
this.http.get(uri, {responseType: 'blob'})
    .subscribe(res =>{
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      a.download = name;
      a.click();
    }, error => {this.errorHandler.addError(this.constructor.name, error);});}
```

Your help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include ResponseContentType from http mudule to download the file.

```
//service file. Create this method in your service file where you added all services.
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

download(uri) {
    return this.http.get(uri, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
    .map((res) => {
        return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' })          //change file type here
    })
}
```

Then create the object of the response using createObjectURL

```
//component.ts
this.service.download(uri)
.subscribe(res => {
    saveAs(res,"filename.ext");
    let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
    window.open(fileURL);
})
```

This is working for all browser.

Comment: saveAs function is undefined, where can i get that?

Comment: You need to install filesaver module to use this function. Please find the detail from here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver